# Chart.js - Charts disappears after animation [Because of Bootstrap Js]

Tags: javascript, laravel, charts

I made a chart with Chart.js but my chart disappears after the animation is finished.

Here's my script code.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

        let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
            type:'line', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
            data:{
                labels:['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
                datasets:[{
                    label:'Sales',
                    data:[
                        500,
                        304,
                        601,
                        670,
                        912,
                        612,
                        500
                    ]
                }]
            },
            options:{}
        });
    </script>
```

And this is how I called `myChart`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="container">
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4

**UPDATE:** I tried debugging it too and found out that it disappears once the javascript of Bootstrap has finished loading.

Comment: Updated. Seems like bootstrap js negates chart js.

Comment: What errors seen on you browser console?

Comment: None. But whenever I take out `<script> bootstrap js cdn here </script>`, my chart shows up. I think there are two function names that are the same from different javascripts.

Comment: The problem could be from the same issue here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066247/9291504

Answer (score 0):

I see that you haven't included the whole code for your view so I guess you have somewhere in your code @endsection. If so then just remove @endsection from your code and test it. This way it should work in Laravel 5.4 with bootstrap.

Comment: FYI: To request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. Thanks!