# ChartJS shows up and disappears

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

So I am using ChartJS alongside a Bootstrap 4 and Laravel Project.
The code is fine(see below). Every time I refresh the page, the chart shows up for like a millisecond and goes away.

```
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div>
                            <canvas id="pie-chart" style="width:100%;"></canvas>
                            <!-- Pie Chart -->
                            <script>
                                new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
                                    type: 'pie',
                                    data: {
                                      labels: ["College Project", "Mind Map", "Designers Club"],
                                      datasets: [{
                                        label: "Population (millions)",
                                        backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#8e5ea2","#3cba9f"],
                                        data: [2478,5267,734]
                                      }]
                                    },
                                    options: {
                                      title: {
                                        display: true,
                                        text: 'Tasks Division'
                                      }
                                    }
                                });
                            </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: When I test your code there seems to be no error. https://jsfiddle.net/eb7u9kjL/ Do you have any other code that is executed?

Comment: I also think some other code have same ID possible and does console brings any error back?

Comment: Weird... There are no other codes with the same ID... 
It's a fresh project.

Comment: can you comment console traceback?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
The problem was from the defer loading of the app.js in the layout.

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

It was loading after my  and a Vue instanciation was created. I think this is why the chart was disappearing.

I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which was working for me:

- **Remove async and defer from app.js**

`<script async src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>`